# How to post this form with month and year to controller action method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following use code in MVC view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BondCompletion", "HrReport", FormMethod.Get))
{
<table class="table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Date : </td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstOrDefault().StartDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
}
```

Here I am using jQueryUI DatePiker and I modify that piker to display only month and year

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
        }
    });    

});

</script>
```

Till here everything is working fine but when I click submit button this form is not posting it’s showing that piker dialog only. I want to post the form when I click on submit button. What should I modify to post this form on submit button click?

Comment: What do you mean _" this form is not posting"_? Is it not hitting the controller? Is the model not binding?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis `)` in your `@Html.EditorFor` helper.

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir this is not hitting the controller action method. whenever i click on submit datePiker open below the the textbox.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console? And I am puzzled by `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstOrDefault().StartDate)` which means you model is a collection, but your generating a input which won't bind to a collection when you post back

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir. I got my ans. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Can't see how that that answer anything to do with the issue you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention you were using jQuery UI.

The way to do it by defining an `altField` with an id of a hidden input

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6s9yLem5/1/

```
<form action="/echo/html/">
    <input type="datetime">
    <input type="hidden" id="myDate" name="myDate">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        altField : '#myDate',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));

        }
    });    

});


$("form").submit(function(){

    $('body').append("Data: "+$(this).serialize());
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks @miro sir. This is what i was searching. Sorry about uncleared question.